# DAML sdk 0.12.24 mvn compile fails after executing daml build

Tags: maven, daml

mvn compile can't find the autogenerated clases in the compiled dar file with version 0.12.24

I have created a smart contract with DAML where with version 0.12.20 if you executed `mvn compile` works and generate the clases correctly.

When upgrading to version 0.12.24 where some bug has been fixed in DAML the `mvn compile` can't find the clases generated in the file.dar i.e:

```
[ERROR] /Users/Pablo/Documents/everis/projects/PoC/stampchain-daml-app/src/main/java/com/digitalasset/quickstart/stampcontract/StampContractMain.java:[10,55] package com.digitalasset.quickstart.model.stampcontract does not exist
```

To assure it was not an issue in my code I've create a new quickstarter project and try the same getting the same error where maven can't compile from the dar.
steps:

1. `daml new quickstart quickstart-java`
2. `cd quickstart`
3. `daml build`
4. `mvn compile`

The output

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (daml-codegen-java) on project daml-quickstart-java: An exception occured while executing the Java class. Input file '/Users/Pablo/Downloads/DAML/tempquickstarter/quickstart/target/daml/iou.dar' doesn't exist -> [Help 1]
```

if you try the same with the sdk version 0.12.20 works and generate the java.

Answer (score 0):

By default `daml build` generates the dar file in `dist/<projectname>.dar` so for your example it will create `dist/quickstart.dar`. However, the codegen in the quickstart example is setup to expect the dar in `target/daml/iou.dar`. You can pass `-o target/daml/iou.dar` to change the output location so the full command is `daml build -o target/daml/iou.dar`. This is also the command used in the [quickstart guide](https://docs.daml.com/getting-started/quickstart.html#run-the-application-using-prototyping-tools). I hope that helps!